# PYMC installation --fcompiler not recognized

Tags: python, osx-mountain-lion, failed-installation, pymc

I'm trying to install pymc on OSX Mountain lion.

I have installed gfortran (from http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries#MacOS) and cloned pymc.

I tried what has previously been working: 'setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build', but this gives an error:

usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]

or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]

or: setup.py --help-commands

or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --fcompiler not recognized

If I just do: 'sudo python setup.py install' then I get this

.

.

.

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

In file included from src/ft2font.cpp:3:

In file included from src/ft2font.h:16:

/usr/X11/include/ft2build.h:56:10: fatal error: 'freetype/config/ftheader.h' file not found

include 
   ^
1 error generated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks,

Jen

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PyMC are you trying to install, the current development version on GitHub master (PyMC 3) or the release version (PyMC 2.3)?

If you are trying to install PyMC 3, you do not need a Fortran compiler. You do need Theano, however. Can you try the following?

```
pip install --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
pip install --no-deps git+git://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc.git
```

Comment: I was trying to install PyMC 3 (but didn't realise). I've been able to install PyMC 2.3 using "python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build" and "python setup.py install". I was hoping though to install a previous commit of PyMC (f733d06bd9aabc4a713daa9c036098841819f673), and for this, I still get the "error: option --fcompiler not recognized".

Comment: sorry, "python setup.py config --fcompiler=gfortran build" for old commit gives: 
Error: Return type mismatch of function 'psi' at (1) (REAL(4)/REAL(8)) error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -ffixed-form -fno-second-underscore -arch x86_64 -fPIC -O3 -funroll-loops -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c -c pymc/flib.f -o build/temp.macosx-10.8-intel-2.7/pymc/flib.o" failed with exit status 1

Comment: I've modified my answer above to help you get PyMC 3 installed. If you want PyMC 2.3, I recommend getting it from PyPI.